# Cloud Functions suitability for Custom Tags

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-functions

I wonder if Google Cloud Functions are a good solution to the following:

For our apps we like to use Google Tag Manager, just like we do for our sites.
Thing is : on the website GTM, we can implement custom tags easily by using javascript.
In an app that's not possible , it would be possible to call a function that's already compiled inside the app.
But that gives a lot of problems with flexibility, for instance: if an app is already used by many users, we need to deploy a new version if we want to implement a new custom tag to a third party.

I was thinking of Google Cloud Functions as an answer, where by using Javascript, we could implement new tags (in the form of api calls) without redeploying.

Question is : how can you call such function without redeploying? And is this a suitable way of doing this.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, this is not possible without planning it ahead of time and it would likely result in a high LOE instead of just adding the tag and releasing a new version of the app.

You would need to setup your app to be able to detect **new tags** returned by the cloud function since you're trying to add tags without releasing a new version of the app.

You would then need to come up with a way of tying that tag to a particular view or location within the app.  In addition, you would then need to have the right code in the right places to make sure that tag is used properly.

**Cloud Storage and JavaScript instances might offer a solution:**
I'm going to use iOS as an example, you could potentially use JavaScriptCore.framework to implement this dynamic capability within the app.  You could store new JavaScript functions in cloud storage.  Then you could use a cloud function to fetch these from Cloud Storage, or you can access Cloud Storage directly from an SDK or URL; you do not even need a cloud function to perform this task.

You would then evaluate these scripts within the app:

```
JSContext *context = [JSContext new];
NSString *jsFunctionText =
        @"var isValidNumber = function(phone) {"
        "    var myTag = 'new custom tag';"
        "    /* use JS Tag Manager SDK to deliver tag information."
        "}";
[context evaluateScript:jsFunctionText];
```

This only solves part of your problem though, since you need to be able to add context to where the function should be pulled from and called.  So again, you need to anticipate your future needs and could potentially over engineer the solution.

I know it's not a solid answer, but it is not a simple problem to solve.